# Find the adjoint operator in Hilbert space $L_2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

We are given $Ax(t) = t\int_0^{t^2} \frac{x(s)}{s}ds$ so I know that I need to find $A^*$ such that $(Ax, y) = (x, A^*y)$. 
$(Ax, y) = \int_0^1 t \int_0^{t^2} \frac{x(s)}{s}ds y(t) dt = \int_0^1 \int_0^{t^2} ty(t)\frac{x(s)}{s}ds dt$ 
Now, I need to get this to equal $(x, A^*y)$, but I don't know how to figure out how to do this.  $(x, A^*y) = \int_0^1 x(s)A^*yds$.  I'm guessing $A^*$ is some integral but I don't know how to get the integral from above to the form $\int_0^1 x(t) [\int$something $ds] dt$ where the thing in brackets would be my adjoint operator.

On another note, I don't really know what $D(A)$ would be.  My guess is its {$x \in L^2(0,1)$}, but I'm not sure so could someone please let me know if this is correct

Comment: You wrote $(Ax,y)$ wrong which is probably why you are confused.

Comment: You have no y there at all.

Comment: @Ian oh I see.  I shall fix it immediately, but that isn't the issue I'm having because I was doing this on paper and on paper I do have a y(t) term in there so do you have any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Change the order of integration and then group everything except $x(s)$ into one aggregate, which will be $A^*y$.

Comment: @Ian so this will equal $\int_0^1 x(t) \int_\sqrt{s}^1 \frac{ty(t)}{s}dtds$ so does that mean that $A^* =  \int_\sqrt{s}^1 \frac{ty(t)}{s}dt$?  Is it ok that there is an s in there?  Also, I know I also need to show the domains are equal. Is my attempt at $D(A)$ correct or am I missing something/including something extra?

Comment: Uh...there is still a problem because that is not of the form $(x,z)$ as it should be.

Comment: You should just change the limits without changing arguments so you have $\int_0^1 x(s) \frac{1}{s} \int_{\sqrt{s}}^1 t y(t) dt ds$. Everything except $x(s)$ inside the ds integral is $(A^*y)(s)$.

Comment: so thats what I had except I meant $x(s)$ in mine, not $x(t)$.  Is that correct?  $A^*y(s) = \frac{1}{s} \int _\sqrt{s} ^1 ty(t) dt$?

Comment: I don't think $A$ is well-defined  since $e.g.$ $1\in L^2(0,1)$ but 
$$
\int_0^{t^2} 1/s\ \mathsf ds
$$
does not exist.

Comment: @Math1000 So do I just need to restrict the domain?  I wasn't really given one

Comment: The domain of $A$ indeed requires some decay condition on $x(t)$ near $t=0$.